# How to remove special characters in a dropdown menu in product view page?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, dropdown-attribute

I am using a dropdown attribute but it is displaying special characters.

Can you please give me a solution for removing special characters in dropdown menu.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you please give screenshot where you excataly talking about?

Comment: How do I remove the +$0.00 from product bundle options?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove special characters you need to use Javascript or Jquery.
Please refer fiddle link below and modify the code accordingly.
[Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/vNfrk/)